# rendering issue when viewing polygons in mollweide projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, rendering

Arc10.3, windows

I am using and etopo bathymetry raster with various polygon, line, and point layers over it.  One of my polygons encompasses the north pole.  This polygon automatically created a line within it that runs to the north pole.  I have not been able to successfully remove this line using editor, and I am very familiar with editor so I have tried quite a few methods. The point that lies on the north pole that is insists on connecting to shows up as a red square in edit mode.

The real issue:

When I view the map at full extent, a polygon appears to circle the entire edge of the sphere.  If I keep the polygon layer filled, the whole map appears as the fill color.  When I zoom in enough that the north pole is not visible, this circle goes away.  Clearly the circle must correlated to the issue I am having with the north pole polygon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the polygon is in a geographic coordinate reference system (GeoCRS) or was projected from one into Mollweide-based Projected CRS, that line probably represents the "closing" line to show that it wraps the pole.

Separately, if zooming in and out causes a polygon to 'flood' the map with color, there is usually something wrong with its topology. It's not quite closed or has lines that cross when it's projected.